# Why do I keep getting Incorrect usage of const UDF in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, red-gate-sql-prompt

I keep getting warnings in SSMS (using v17.7) and RedGate SQL Prompt:

> Incorrect usage of const UDF

It underlines `SYSUTCDATETIME()`

The following underlines `SYSUTCDATETIME()` in both places

```
   SELECT 2
     FROM (VALUES (CAST('2020-06-26' AS DATETIME2(7)))) AS s (SampleAt)
    WHERE s.SampleAt BETWEEN SYSUTCDATETIME() AND DATEADD(DAY, 100, SYSUTCDATETIME())
```

The following doesn't underline it at all:

```
    SELECT 2
     WHERE CAST('2020-06-26' AS DATETIME2(7)) BETWEEN SYSUTCDATETIME() AND DATEADD(DAY, 100, SYSUTCDATETIME())
```

Also doesn't underline it at all:

```
DECLARE @now AS DATETIME2 = SYSUTCDATETIME()

   SELECT 2
     FROM (VALUES (CAST('2020-06-26' AS DATETIME2(7)))) AS s (SampleAt)
    WHERE s.SampleAt BETWEEN @now AND DATEADD(DAY, 100, @now)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spoke with the developers. This is a bug in the tool. Thanks for identifying it. They're actively working to get a fix in place and it should be published soon.

Answer (score 1):

As of today (I just bought and installed the latest SQLPROMPT) this is still a bug. The only "fix" I could implement was to disable code analysis in the RedGate options. This disables all code analysis but there doesn't seem to be a way to disable just this rule like there are for other analysis rules.

Answer (score 0):

This is still a bug as of 31-March-2024.

You can make the green wavy line go away by putting SYSUTCDATETIME() in a variable (DATETIME2 or DATETIMEOFFSET etc.) and then using that variable instead of SYSUTCDATETIME(). In the example given in the original question, the following code is "green wavy line free":

DECLARE @Now DATETIME2(7) = SYSUTCDATETIME()

SELECT 2
FROM (VALUES (CAST('2024-06-26' AS DATETIME2(7)))) AS s (SampleAt)
WHERE s.SampleAt BETWEEN @Now AND DATEADD(DAY, 100, @Now)